# addition of HBr to a conjugated alkene

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, electrophilic-substitution

[image]

[image]

here we shift double bond and change the carbocation from 3 degree to 2 degree, by doing so we are saying that hindrance matters more than carbocation stability, is this always the case in such reactions ? the carbocation and the 3 degree carbon are both sp2, does hindrance play a major role in triangular planar structures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thought is correct, but the application not quite. You are correct, the resonance structures vary from secondary and tertiary carbocation, because the proton will attack the double bond at the end of the molecule to form the more stable carbocation, but: The more substituted alkene will be considerably more stable. The product you have drawn is substituted three times, but the product you are thinking about is only substituted two times. (If the Bromide ion attacks the tertiary carbocation.).

Answer (score 2):

You should not consider the two carbocations distinct. They are one and the same, the identical molecule. There will be a fractional positive charge observable on the tertiary carbon and a fractional positive charge observable on the secondary one. Looking at orbitals, there is just one LUMO (lowest unoccupied molecular orbital) which in first approximation has large lobes on the tertiary and secondary carbon and nowhere else – a simple allylic system.

There are three effects that influence where the bromine will attack. First, the trisubstituted double bond is more stable than a disubstituted one, meaning the product is thermodynamically favoured. Second, attack on the secondary carbon is less hindered sterically, meaning that the product is also kinetically favoured. And finally, bromide can re-dissociate to a certain extent regenerating the carbocation; it is more likely to do so as a tertiary bromide, again tipping the scales in the direction of product d.